# VPC two types of nexus 7700

Tags: cisco-nexus, vpc

Can we VPC two types of nexus 7700 with each other? I mean , we want to VPC one Nexus 7710 with Nexus 7718.

Does it possible ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, this can't be done. The models have to be the same even if they're models in the same family.